# How can I do an Rspec test on date of birth format by stubbing out Time.Now?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, stub

This is the validation of date of birth and I need to test it out using rspec.

`validates :date_of_birth, date: { before: Proc.new { Date.today }, message: 'must be before today' }, on: :create`

This is what I did but it doesn't seem to be right

```
it "should allow valid birth date" do
date_of_birth = Time.now
allow(Time).to receive(:now).and_return(date_of_birth)

date_of_birth.capture_item("date of birth")
expect(date_of_birth.items[0].date_captured).to eq(date_of_birth)
end
```

Comment: what is `capture_item`?

Comment: I don't think you need to stub `Time#now`, just set the date_of_birth to a date in the past, call `#valid?` and check for an error.

Answer (score 1):

```
it 'should allow valid birth date' do
  person = Person.new(date_of_birth: Date.yesterday)
  person.valid?
  expect(person.errors[:date_of_birth]).to include('must be before today')
end
```